Attempt to derive Taylor expansion using discrete time steps
I was playing around trying to check if the $n$th order Taylor approximation about $0$ can be explained and obtained by using a physical reasoning argument like below for the case $n = 2$ (that is given $f(0),f’(0)$ and $f’’(0)$ and thinking of $f$ as the position of a car after $t$ seconds).
To estimate $f(t),$ with $f’(0),f’’(0)$, divide $t$ by $2$ (ideally $n$ in the general case) and estimate $f$ at those time steps.
So after $t/2$ seconds, the position can be estimated as $f(0)+f’(0)t/2$.
Also, its velocity is approximately $f’(0)+f’’(0)t/2$.
Now, having lost info about the acceleration, the best we can do is use the estimated position and velocity after $t/2$ seconds to estimate $f(t)$ as
\begin{align*}
f(t/2)+f’(t/2)t/2 &= f(0)+f’(0)t/2 [f’(0)+f’’(0)t/2]t/2 \\
&= f(0)+f’(0)+f’’(0)/2
\end{align*}
which checks out with the $n =2$ Taylor expansion. Using a similar logic for $n = 3$ (take steps of size $t/3$) I think that the pattern breaks and it doesn’t match what it should be for Taylor. I concretely got as an estimate $f(0)+f’(0)+f’’(0)(t^2)/3+f’’’(0)(t)^3/9.$ Could someone else do it and let me known if it breaks in fact?

If I understand this correctly, the first estimates are $(i),f(t/2)\approx f(0)+f’(0)\tfrac{t}{2}$ and $(ii),f’(t/2)\approx f’(0)+f’’(0)\tfrac{t}{2}.$ And $(iii),f(t)\approx f(t/2) + f’(t/2)\tfrac{t}{2}.$ Plugging $(i)$ and $(ii)$ into $(iii)$ then gives
$f(t)\approx f(0)+f’(0)\tfrac{t}{2} + \left(f’(0)+f’’(0)\tfrac{t}{2}\right) \tfrac{t}{2}.$ Simplifying gives $f(t)\approx f(0) + f’(0)t + f’’(0)\tfrac{t^2}{4}$.

Simple example that fails: "the position of a car after t seconds" -- what if that car drives circles and after t seconds it is always at the same spot, you'll conclude "it does not move at all". That is correct overall, but at the end of the day the gasoline is gone somehow ;) -- I'd like to show that I'm not convinced by your ansatz to find a Taylor approximation.
